# Do I need to use hashes instead of user id's for invite system?

Tags: security

I'm implementing a referral system, and I'm wondering if I NEED to use a hash as the referrer_id, or if I can just use the user's id?  I don't want to dogmatically use hashes for EVERYTHING, so can you give me some examples of potential pitfalls?

Comment: Normally you would use hashes due to their unpredictability. Would you need it here?

Comment: Hashes always produce the same output for the same input, so they would be predictable if all you use for input is the user ID

Comment: From a security standpoint, it depends on what you mean by user ID, how it's used throughout the application, and how sensitive it might be. If user ID is, for example, just a username like blacktie24, it might not be any security problem; if, however, you allow folks to change their user ID, you may not want this.

Comment: @Noyo, user id meaning the auto incremented integer that serves as the primary key of the user record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what is important to you.  If you need to know for sure that the referrer_id originated from the user who provided the refer, then you will need some sort of hash combined with token that cannot be guessed.  If all you do is hash the user id, you aren't providing any real security because an attacker could simply guess a user ID and hash it to make your server happy.

It is important to know that hashing does not produce any unpredictability.  It will *always* produce the same output for the same input.  Hashing is valuable because it prevents tampering (a small change in input produces a large change in output) and it normalizes the size of the data, but it should never be confused with encryption.

How much do you care about Confidentiality, Integrity, and Availability of the referrer_id?  The answers to those questions will determine how much effort you need to exert to protect the referrer_id.

Comment: In response to creating a hash, I second that hashing known or guessable input does not increase security, but if you choose your input to the hash function carefully and, for example, concatenate said input with a secret, it should be a fine replacement to the id-only approach. (Caveat: You'd want to make sure the secret is used only for the one purpose of generating these hashes!)

Comment: @Freedom_Ben I would probably concatenate the user's email address with a random string of a specific length and then hash that.  But I guess my problem is that I'm not really sure how much I care about confidentiality/integrity/availability of the referrer_id because I don't really know what the consequences are of people knowing them.

Comment: @Noyo Yes, I would agree with that, although if confidentiality is the goal then encryption is superior, because you don't need to know the plaintext in order to recover it.  If you use a secret value as part of the hash, then you need both the secret value and the user ID in order to recover the plaintext.  It would work ok, but it adds unnecessary work since hashing algorithms are one-way only.  Recovering the user ID would require hashing all user ID's with the secret bits and comparing them to the passed in the hash to find out who generated them.

Comment: @blacktie24 If you care to know for sure who it was that made the referral, then you should care about confidentiality (and should therefore encrypt & hash the User ID).  If you care that only users who were actually referred can get access, then you care about Integrity.  Even if you only care about the referral for statistical purposes and not security, I would still implement it with encryption/hashing so your data is "pure."  If it is just for marketing purposes entirely (making the product scarce can be good for generating desire), then perhaps you don't care about either.

Comment: @Freedom_Ben, I wasn't very clear, but in a hashing approach, the hash would only be used for the verification of other information in the referral request, such as referrer and "referral source" (if it's one-to-one referrals), which would be some indexed field in the DB (not the primary key). And depending on the use case, a hashing approach could be less prone to a DoS attack, since hashing known values and comparing is generally faster than decrypting a string that could potentially be garbage.